# Move marker for point X feet due east

Tags: qgis, symbology, point

I'm trying to offset a symbol X feet due East from it's original location, where X is controlled by a real data column ("DBH").

I've gotten as far as making a new marker layer in my style, and changing the units to "map unit".  I can offset it a fixed distance, but am stuck on how to do it with a field.

```
make_point($x+"DBH", $y)
```

seemed logical to me, but it isn't working.  I've tried type casting DBH with to_real, I've tried geom_to_wkt.

Answer (score 1):

The following formula worked for me (QGIS 2.16):

```
make_point(x($geometry)+ "POPULATION" ,y($geometry))
```

But the tries I made with $x,$y failed. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

After spending WAY TOO LONG barking up the wrong tree, it suddenly occurred to me that I wasn't actually making a point, but giving coordinates.  That lead me to the `'x, y'`  notation.  After another session of my brain not working well, I ended up with `format('%1,%2',0.00000406*("DBH"/24), '0')`.  In my particular case, DBH is the diameter of the offset in inches (thus the divide by 24).